# Using sed/awk to print lines with matching pattern OR another matching pattern

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I need to print lines in a file matching a pattern *OR* a different pattern using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) or [sed](/questions/tagged/sed). I feel like this is an easy task but I can't seem to find an answer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The POSIX way

```
awk '/pattern1/ || /pattern2/{print}'
```

#### Edit

To be fair, I like *lhf*'s way better via `/pattern1|pattern2/` since it requires less typing for the same outcome.  However, I should point out that this template cannot be used for **logical AND** operations, for that you need to use my template which is `/pattern1/ && /pattern2/`

Comment: thanks, this worked great. i can never figure out whether sed or awk is appropriate for a given task. is there any big difference i am missing? or different ways to do the same thing?

Comment: @rick, yes there is. awk is a programming language. sed is not really so practically. (although its turing complete).

Comment: @rick I generally only use `sed` for simple text replacement as in `s/foo/bar/g` or what have you.  For cases where you want to print out only a portion of a given line, I generally look to `awk` for most applications although `sed` can be coerced to do it with some regex magic.  If you ever have a problem that deals with any sense of 'fields' whatever the delimiter may be, you pretty much always want to go with `awk` in that case.  Also, it is never correct to pipe the output of `awk` to `grep` or vice versa.  You can always combine those two inside of `awk`.

Answer (score 28):

Use:

```
sed -nr '/patt1|patt2/p'
```

where `patt1` and `patt2` are the patterns.  If you want them to match the whole line, use:

```
sed -nr '/^(patt1|patt2)$/p'
```

You can drop the `-r` and add escapes:

```
sed -n '/^\(patt1\|patt2\)$/p'
```

for POSIX compliance.

Answer (score 12):

why dont you want to use grep?

```
grep -e 'pattern1' -e 'pattern2'
```

Comment: One possible reason is "the -P option only supports a single pattern", hence with multiple `-e`s, you won't be able to use Perl RegExp such as \d with GNU's Grep.

Comment: How about something like `egrep 'pattern1|pattern2'`?

Comment: If sed can do everything that grep can do (and a lot more), then why learn the command that can only do the limited subset of things?  Happy 50th birthday, sed!

Answer (score 9):

`awk '/PATT1|PATT2/ { print }'`