# awk: match regex with or operator of two shell variables

Tags: regex, bash, awk, or-operator

I am trying to use different stuff with `awk`.
First, the use of some shell variables, which [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19075707/316232) shows how to use them.
Second, how to use a shell variable to match a pattern, which [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39384347/316232) points to use `~` operator.
Finally, I want to use some kind of [or operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5385259/316232) to match two shell variables.

Putting all together in `foo.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

START_TEXT="My start text"
END_TEXT="My end text"

awk -v start=$START_TEXT -v end=$END_TEXT '$0 ~ start || $0 ~ end { print $2 }' myfile
```

Which fails to run:

```
$ ./foo.sh 
awk: fatal: cannot open file `text' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

So I think the OR-operator (`||`) does not work well with regex `~` operator.
I was guessing I may need to do the OR-thing inside the regex.
So I tried these two:

```
awk -v start=$START_TEXT -v end=$END_TEXT '$0~/start|end/ { print $2 }' myfile
awk -v start=$START_TEXT -v end=$END_TEXT '$0~start|end { print $2 }' myfile
```

With same failed result.
And even this thing fails...

```
awk -v start=$START_TEXT '$0~start { print $2 }' myfile
```

So I am doing something really wrong...
Any hints how to achieve this?

Comment: quote your shell variables `awk -v start="$START_TEXT" -v end="$END_TEXT" ...`

Comment: Yeah! That made it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the `regex` `OR` like this:

```
awk -v start="$START_TEXT" -v end="$END_TEXT" '$0~ start "|" end { print $2 }' myfile
```

`awk` knows the parameter passed to `~` operator is a regex, so we can just process it by insert the `|` or operator between two strings.

Also there's another way to pass variables into `awk`, like this:

```
awk '$0~ start "|" end { print $2 }' start="$START_TEXT" end="$END_TEXT" myfile
```

This will increase conciseness. But since it's less intuitive, so use it with caution.

Comment: Is `$0~ start "|" end` quicker than `$0~start || $0~end` ?

Comment: @nephewtom  I'm not sure, I think it will be a tiny bit faster. However here I mainly show a different way of using it, and it's a little bit more concise :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems @jxc pointed my problem in the comments: the shell variables need to be quoted.

```
awk -v start="$START_TEXT" -v end="$END_TEXT" '$0~start || $0~end { print $2 }' myfile
```

That made it work!